# Drupal - Search API - Views - Solr Index: How to implement a Date Filter?

Tags: drupal, view

Looking to incorporate a date filter within a Solr Index View. Presently the only option is for the user to manually enter a text date to filter by date. It would be nice to expose a date filter and search by M/d/Y using the 'Between' function which is available in the 'Content' View. Creating a 'Solr Index' View seems to remove that functionality.

I noticed that the Between operator is missing from handler_filter.inc within the Search API module:

```
public function operator_options() {
    return array(
      '<' => t('Is smaller than'),
      '<=' => t('Is smaller than or equal to'),
      '=' => t('Is equal to'),
      '<>' => t('Is not equal to'),
      '>=' => t('Is greater than or equal to'),
      '>' => t('Is greater than'),
    );
  }
```

What other code would we need to modify in order to get a more user-friendly date filter available for the user to query?

Comment: I have a same issue,did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that:

```
$or = $query->createFilter('AND');
$or->condition('created', $start_date, '>=');
$or->condition('created', $end_date, '<=');
$query->filter($or);
```

in `hook_search_api_query_alter`.